# Integrating FlatIcon with Rails 6/Webpacker (Fonts with Webpack)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am trying to use Flaticon fonts using Webpacker. I am getting the following error from all of my fonts when Webpacker compiles:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/Flaticon.ttf' in '/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/my_app/app/javascript/stylesheets'
 @ ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss) 7:36-68
 @ ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

**Under app/assets/fonts:**

```
* Flaticon.eot
* Flaticon.svg
* Flaticon.tff
* Flaticon.woff
* Flaticon.woff2
```

**Under javascript/stylesheets/_flaticon.scss:**

```
    /*
    Flaticon icon font: Flaticon
    Creation date: 03/04/2020 21:12
    */

    @font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../fonts/Flaticon.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../fonts/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("../fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

    .fi:before{
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Flaticon";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        text-transform: none;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .flaticon-policeman:before { content: "\f100"; }

    $font-Flaticon-policeman: "\f100";
```

**Under config/webpacker.yml:**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

I have tried to move the fonts folder to vendor and under javascript, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to move them from `app/assets/fonts` to `app/javascript/fonts` so Webpacker can pick them up?

Comment: @kinduff That worked! Thank you so so much :)!